# Retrieving cell data from a selected cell in a tablewidget

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtablewidget

I am making a stock control program and i have hit a problem with getting the value of a selected cell, i know i need to use "QtGui.QTableWidget.currentRow" and "QtGui.QTableWidget.currentColumn" to get the item's position. However i cannot seem to get this to work because when the functions are called nothing has been selected and so it returns -1,-1

Does anyone know how to get it so it runs the "QtGui.QTableWidget.currentRow" and "QtGui.QTableWidget.currentColumn" everytime the user selects a cell?

i think the code i need to get the actual data once i have the co-ords is  QtGui.QTableWidget.item ?

This is the code i am using to get the row and column:

```
row = self.table.currentRow
column = self.table.currentColumn
self.ID = self.table.item(row, column)
```

when the user clicks a button to add stock the program should then use the product code it will have just got to make the change to the database after getting the quantity added from the user

I am using python 3.2 and pyqt 4

any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Sam

Comment: if you could post a code snippet it might i) help us understand and ii) help you explain

Comment: UPDATE: 
I am now able to retrieve the cell item, however it is returning the actual item rather than the data

    
def getCell(self):
row = self.table.currentRow()
print(row)

self.ID = self.table.item(row, 0)
print(self.ID)

this returns <PyQt4.QtGui.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x0000000006509488> rather than "14"

can anyone help?

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer :-) you want to call `item.text()` on the item you've had returned.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When the `QTableWidget` sees that someone has clicked one of it's cells, it will emit a `cellClicked` event - which you need to connect to. Maybe something like

```
self.table.cellClicked.connect(self.cell_was_clicked)
```

could be in your setup code, 
and the function `cell_was_clicked` might be something like

```
def cell_was_clicked(self, row, column):
    print("Row %d and Column %d was clicked" % (row, column))
    item = self.table.itemAt(row, column)
    self.ID = item.text()
```

I've not used `currentRow` and `currentColumn` as you want a response on the `click`. This function is documented [here](http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget.cellClicked) (sorry, I prefer pyside - it's pretty much the same as PyQT). Note also `itemAt` instead of just `item` - as you will get the item at the cell, not it's contents. Use the `.text()` function of `QTableWidgetItem` to get at the contents.

Note - this is using 'slots and signals' and in particular the 'new style'. As you're using PyQT4 and Python 3 you should have no trouble with 'new stuff' :-)

You might consider browsing a slots and signals [tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/04/24/new-style-signal-slot-connection-mechanism-in-pyqt/) - that might straighten a few of these abstract concepts out. Good luck!

Comment: row = self.table.currentRow()
        print(row)

        self.item = self.table.item.text(row, 0)
        self.ID = self.item.text()
        print(self.ID)

this doesn't want to work for me? 
i get this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\College\Computing\Stock control\Coding\Stock Control GUI.py", line 453, in getCell
    self.item = self.table.item.text(row, 0)
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: So that sounds like `item` isn't a `QTableWidgetItem` - see what `print(type(self.item))` produces and then look that up in the manual.

Comment: ahhh, i just noticed i slight error in my code, i'd kept item instead of using itemAt. its working perfectly now, i can carry on and get this program finished :L

Comment: just wondering if i could get a little more help, how do i convert this [('example data', 'example data', 'example data', 'example data')] to this [(example data),(example data),(example data),(example data)] ??

Comment: You probably aught to open a new question... If `example data` is a numerical value, then if `x =  [('example data', 'example data', 'example data', 'example data')]` then `[float(e) for e in x[0]]` will return a list of floats - and you have a nested list, hence the `x[0]`

Comment: okay, no worries then, i'll keep trying and maybe open a new question if don't get anywhere

Answer (score 1):

here is the code that worked for me:

```
def get_selected_cell_value():
    current_row = self.sold_items_details_table.currentRow()
    current_column = self.sold_items_details_table.currentColumn()
    cell_value = table.item(current_row, current_column).text()
```